# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Email' to data type int

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

I have a stored procedure that is getting data from some other database tables and and putting them into another table. I am running into an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Email' to data type int.

However, I don't see where/how a data conversion would take place.

I have checked the data types for both where I am getting the email address and where I am inserting the email address. They are both set to `varchar(255)`.

```sql
DECLARE @prefix varchar(50), @middle varchar(50), @suffix varchar(50), 
        @companyID int, @companyNm varchar(100),
        @badge varchar(50), @title varchar(100), @salutation varchar(50), 
        @pplType int, @email varchar(255), @specialty int, 
        @mailpref int, @source int, 
        @add1 varchar(100), @add2 varchar(100), @city varchar(50), 
        @state varchar(50), @zip varchar(50), @countryID int, 
        @phone varchar(50), @ext varchar(50), @fax varchar(50), 
        @addID int, @addType int, @arrival datetime, @departure datetime, 
        @regType varchar(50), @mtRegID int

SELECT @regType = regType 
FROM Registration 
WHERE personID = @personID AND meetingCode = @meetingCode

SELECT 
    @prefix = [Name Prefix], @middle = Middle, @suffix = [Name Suffix], 
    @companyID = [Company ID], @companyNm = [Company Name], 
    @badge = [Badge Name], @title = Title, 
    @salutation = Salutation, @pplType = [People Type], 
    @email = Email, @specialty = [Specialty ID], @mailpref = MailPref, 
    @source = [Source ID] 
FROM  
    MeetingtrakTest.dbo.tblPeople 
WHERE 
    [Person ID] = @personID

SELECT 
    @add1 = Address1, @add2 = Address2, @city = City, @state = State, 
    @zip = Zip, @countryID = [Country Id],
    @phone = Phone, @ext = Extension, @fax = Fax, @addID = [Address ID] 
FROM 
    MeetingtrakTest.dbo.tblPeopleAddresses 
WHERE 
    [Person ID] = @personID AND [Primary] = 1

SELECT 
    @arrival = [Meeting Start Date], @departure = [Meeting End Date] 
FROM 
    MeetingtrakTest.dbo.tblMeetings 
WHERE 
    [Meeting Code] = @meetingCode

INSERT INTO tblRegistration ([Person Id], [Pre or On-Site], [Attendee List], [Use Company Name], [Reg Date], [Use Housing Costs], [Use Itinerary Costs], Attended, [Date Entered], [Entered By], [Date Updated], [First Name], [Last Name], [Meeting Code], [Registration Code], [Name Prefix], Middle, [Name Suffix], [Company ID], [Company Name], [Badge Name], Title, Salutation, [People Type], [Email], [Specialty ID], MailPref, Source, [Address 1], [Address 2], City, State, Zip, [Country ID], Phone, Extension, Fax, [Address Id] ,[Address Type], [Arrival Date], [Departure Date]) 
VALUES (@personID, 1, 1, 1, GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0, GETDATE(), 'etrak', GETDATE(), @first, @last, @meetingCode, @regType, @prefix, @middle, @suffix, @companyID, @companyNm, @badge, @title, @salutation, @pplType, @email, @specialty, @mailpref, @source, @add1, @add2, @city, @state, @zip, @countryID, @phone, @ext, @fax, @addID, @addType, @arrival, @departure); 

SET @mtRegID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: Simplify your code to isolate the problem.

Comment: most likely it happened in the `Insert` part, it was doing the implicit conversion. check the mapping carefully